# Redirect one domain to another in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I am looking to one domain to another with all sub-urls as well. The original url would be ehanceinsdev.com and the redirected url would be www.enhanceinsurance.com. I would want it so that enhanceinsdev.com/foo would go to www.enhanceinsurance.com/foo.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are they both on the same server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this simple rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^enhanceinsdev\.wpengine\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.enhanceinsurance.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Hello, please note that I got the first domain wrong, it is actually enhanceinsdev.wpengine.com (it's a subdomain). I still tried what you suggested and it didn't work. Thanks!

Comment: Ok answer updated. Make sure this is in `DocumentRoot` of `enhanceinsdev.wpengine.com` host.

Comment: Thanks, apparently my host doesn't allow domain-level 301 redirects through their .htaccess. I ended up having to write it in their admin panel using regex. Weird but it worked. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ehanceinsdev\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.enhanceinsurance.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hey buddy, enhancedev.com\.com? I think you may want to check your answer.

Comment: @ZachRussell Yes it was a typo. Should be fixed.